# Reusing certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a website (public facing) and a message queue (internal only) on the same server. Traffic to both is over ssl. Is there a reason why not to use the same certificate to run both the site and the mq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be restrictions for DNS names used in the certificates. Your public website uses certificate with CN=somedomain.org but internal MQ could have certificate with CN=myinternalserver.local. According to CA Browser forum publicly trusted CA (that are distributed with browsers by default) can not issue a certificate on with this DNS name.

Another reason would be that you don't want to reveal the MQ service to the world and therefore you issue 2 different certificates. This has another advantage. If private key that websites uses is stolen (like in Heartbleed  attack if I remember correctly) you would have to revoke and make only new certificate (and private key) for website. MQ would be unaffected because it was not public.

But IMHO in general you can reuse the same certificate if you can secure the private key properly (i.e. stored in HSM).